# Flutter cocoa pods not installing frameworks

Tags: swift, flutter, cocoapods

I have a `swift project` and a `flutter project`. My `swift project` imports my `certain framework` which has some `pod dependencies` which when i import the `certain framework` then on the `swift project` everything works fine as all dependencies are linked and when i go to `pods/Target Support Files/Pods-**/Pods-**-framework` i can see some similar to this

```
if [[ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Debug" ]]; then
  install_framework "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.framework"
  install_framework "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/FirebaseCoreInternal/FirebaseCoreInternal.framework"
  install_framework "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/FirebaseInstallations/FirebaseInstallations.framework"
  install_framework "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/GTMSessionFetcher/GTMSessionFetcher.framework"
  install_framework "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport.framework"
  install_framework "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/GoogleToolboxForMac/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework"
  install_framework "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities.framework"
  install_framework "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/PromisesObjC/FBLPromises.framework"
  install_framework "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/Protobuf/Protobuf.framework"
  install_framework "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/nanopb/nanopb.framework"
fi
if [[ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Release" ]]; then
  install_framework "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.framework"
  install_framework "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/FirebaseCoreInternal/FirebaseCoreInternal.framework"
  install_framework "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/FirebaseInstallations/FirebaseInstallations.framework"
  install_framework "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/GTMSessionFetcher/GTMSessionFetcher.framework"
  install_framework "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport.framework"
  install_framework "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/GoogleToolboxForMac/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework"
  install_framework "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities.framework"
  install_framework "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/PromisesObjC/FBLPromises.framework"
  install_framework "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/Protobuf/Protobuf.framework"
  install_framework "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/nanopb/nanopb.framework"
fi
if [ "${COCOAPODS_PARALLEL_CODE_SIGN}" == "true" ]; then
  wait
fi
```

Now in flutter i opened the Runner.app and did the same thing as my swift project but whenever i build for a physical device within the Target support files i don't see anything

```
if [[ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Debug" ]]; then
fi
if [[ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Profile" ]]; then
fi
if [[ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Release" ]]; then
fi
if [ "${COCOAPODS_PARALLEL_CODE_SIGN}" == "true" ]; then
  wait
fi
```

Thats why when I launch the app I always get SomeFramework not found e.t.c

What i have tried
`pod deintergate` then `pod install` with no luck on that though the app runs but crashes on that.